# Big O time and space complexity of LZ77

Tags: compression, lz77

What is the Time and space
complexities of the
LZ77 compression algorithm?
I'm trying to implement the algorithm with the best possible space and time complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say with respect to what variable. If you mean the length of the input data, which we will call *n*, then the time and space is always O(*n*). LZ77 is applied to a fixed-size window on the data that slides over it, where that size is independent of *n*.

Comment: Thanks I did want it with respect to the input length (n) I forgot to specify with respect to what variable sorry and thanks for your help